# Tensorflow sports predictions

Tags: python, mongodb, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to work on an **AI that composes possible winning bets**. However I don't know how I should approach this way of AI. I've made simple AI's that can detect the differenace between humans and animals for example, but this one is a lot more complex.

**Which AI model should I use?** I don't think linear regression and K-Nearest Neighbours will work in this situation. I'm trying to experiment with neural networks but I don't have any experience with them.

To make things a little bit more clear.

- I have a MongoDB with fixtures, leagues, countries and predictions
- A **fixture** contains two teams, a league id, and some more values
- A **league** containes a country and some more values
- A **country** is just an ID with for example a flag in SVG format
- A **prediction** is a collection of different **markets*** with their probability

market = a way to place a bet for example: home wins, away wins, both teams score

I also have a collection that contains information about **which league's predictions are most accurate**.

**How would I go about creating this AI**. All data is in a very decent form I just don't know how to begin. For example what **AI model to use**, and **what inputs to use**. Also, how would I go about **saving the AI model and training it with new data** that enters the MongoDB? (I have multiple cron jobs inserting data in the MongoDB)

Note:

- The AI should compose bets containing X number of fixtures

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no "Right" way to do this, I'll tell you the most generic way.
The first thing you want to figure out is the target of the model:

1. The label/target that you want to classify is the market.I can suggest for the simplicity you can use -1 for home , 0 for tie and 1 for  away.
2. data cleaning : remove outliers , complete/interpolate missing values etc.
3. feature extraction:

   - convert categorical values using one-hot encoding.
   - standardise between 0~1 the values of numeric features.
   - Remove all of the non relevant values: that has very low
     [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) over the whole dataset or very high entropy within each
     of the labels.
   - try to extract logical features from the raw data that might help the classifier distinguish between the classes.
4. select features using (for example) mutual information gain.
5. try using simple model as Naive Base, if you have more time you can use SVM model.and remember - *no free lunch theory* and also *less is more* -always prefer simple features and models.